# ansible command to kill specific processes by PID

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to write a command to kill a process by its PID. My issue is that there is only one instance of the process I want to kill in a list of the same process. Basically once i grep, I need the one that's in "bin/{process}" under a specific user only. There are other results in the grep of {process} running that don't match that criteria. This is where I'm at

```html
- name: Get process
    shell: "ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -w bin/{{ PROCESS }} | grep 'id -u {{ USER }}' | awk '{print $2}'"
    register: _process

  - name: Kill running processes
    shell: "kill -9 {{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ _process.stdout_lines }}"

  - wait_for:
     path: "/proc/{{ item }}/status"
     state: absent
    with_items: "{{ _process.stdout_lines }}"
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: killed_process
```

Comment: Running `grep 'id -u {{ USER }}'` does not do what you think it does, since it will look for the literal string `id -u ` followed by whatever is in `{{ USER }}`. Perhaps you wanted `| grep $(id -u {{ USER }}) | awk` to cause the shell to run `id -u` and plug in the result. That said, if you are invoking `awk` at the end anyway, why not save yourself the tremendous headache and just use it for all of that work? Or, you may find [`pgrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/pgrep.1.html) handy, too

Comment: i found that within the environment i'm looking in at any time, the only time i could potentially kill the wrong app from a wrong user is in very specific and not critical times, so I decided on a simple pkill command.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but I will post an answer in case anyone else has this issue (which I just ran up against and saw this post).

Your code is (mostly) correct and should work correctly. The only change you need to make is in your initial `ps` command.
`ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -w bin/{{ PROCESS }} | grep 'id -u {{ USER }}' | awk '{print $2}'`

pgrep can do everything you are looking for without all the pipes. The arguments are:
`-u {{ USER }}`: Only look for processes owned bu the user named USER
`-f 'bin/{{ PROCESS }}'`: Match the full command line (normally pgrep only matches against the process name) for anything that matches bin/PROCESS
The command returns the PIDs of all commands that match.
If matches are found, return 0. If nothing matches, return 1. A return code > 1 is an actual error. see the man page for pgrep for details.

Therefore, your fist task will look like this:
`- name: Get process`
    `shell: "pgrep -u {{ USER }} -f 'bin/{{ PROCESS }}'"`
    `register: _process`
    `failed_when: _process.rc > 1`